Mantine ScrollArea support for FullCalendar views
How can I use ScrollArea from the Mantine library with FullCalendar views?
Now I see the default scrollbars, but I want to change it.

Have you tried anything? Have you got a specific problem? See also [ask]

@ADyson Nope. I thought about the custom view. But it's hard to implement. It needs a lot of things.
